# Cannot add two hyperlinks at the same time using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an application using ASP.Net MVC. I am trying to put all my Submenu at the side navigation when I click on a dropdown. Since I have multiple Submenus for a single dropdown, I would like to put all of it to the side navigation. I use this code:

```
<li id="dd_vehicle" class="dropdown">
<a id="x_btn" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >VEHICLE <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li id="item_registration">
        @if (Utils.IsAdmin())
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Registration", "Registration", "Home")
        }
    </li>
    @*}*@


    <li id="item_modify">
        @Html.ActionLink("Modify", "Modify", "Home")
    </li>

    <li id="item_history">
        @Html.ActionLink("History", "History", "Home")
    </li>

    <li id="item_vehicle_transaction">
        @Html.ActionLink("Transaction", "Transaction", "Home")
    </li>
</ul>
</li>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#x_btn').on('click', function (evt) {
    //evt.preventDefault();

    $('#links_area').html('<a href="@Url.Action("Registration", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">Registration</a>');
    $('#links_area').html('<a href="@Url.Action("TransactionReport", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</a>');

    });
});
```

The problem is, I cannot put two of the links at the same time. the "#links_area" holds only one of the links and it is the last link to be added. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `html()`, or just add all the HTML with a single `html()`.

Comment: $('#links_area').html('<a href="@Url.Action("Registration", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">Registration</a>'+ '<a href="@Url.Action("TransactionReport", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</a>');

Comment: or simply use append() as suggested by @Teemu

Comment: .html() will remove the previous content and add new content. So use .append() as suggested by @Teemu ... .append() will keep the old content & add the new content below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#x_btn').on('click', function (evt) {
        //evt.preventDefault();
        $('#links_area').append('<a href="@Url.Action("Registration", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">Registration</a>');
        $('#links_area').append('<a href="@Url.Action("TransactionReport", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</a>');

    });
});
```